# Guzzle request failing depending on the network I am connected,

Tags: guzzle

I am using guzzle to make request to my subdomain api.domain.com. 
On the same phone hotspot. When I am at home, my guzzle request needs to have www.api.domain.com but anywhere near work, it takes api.domain.com and failed with the www. I can't figure why, this is happening.

Here's my code. Sometimes it works like that without any issue.

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
         'base_uri' => 'https://api.domain.com',
         'timeout'  => 10

     ]);
```

In my controllers

```
 $get = $this->client->request('GET','/dashboard', [
            'timeout' => 0,
            'headers'=>[
            ],
            'form_params'=> ['param'=>$param]
          ]);
```

But when I change locations and it doesn't work. I need to modify it by adding the www

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
         'base_uri' => 'https://www.api.domain.com',
         'timeout'  => 10

     ]);
```

my controllers stay the same and it works

```
 $get = $this->client->request('GET','/dashboard', [
            'timeout' => 0,
            'headers'=>[
            ],
            'form_params'=> ['param'=>$param]
          ]);
```

I get a guzzle cUrl error 6

My .htaccess looks like this in my api. I am not that knowledgeable with htaccess so do correct me if I made a mistakes.

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
  RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
  RewriteRule .* - [e=Authorization:%1]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]

  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.api.domain\.com [NC]
  RewriteRule (.*) https://api.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I think you need to apply www redirection on your api server.

Comment: @LeKhiem Thanks you. I added the redirection on cpanel. it still doesn't work properly. Weirdly every request using always ajax worked without any issue.

Comment: oh why did you add it in the cpanel? I think you should add it in .htaccess file or nginx config

Comment: @LeKhiem Ok, I will try it that way. I can only check if it will work tomorrow when I move to different places .

Comment: let me know if it's still not working.

Comment: @LeKhiem I followed this tutorial to help me. So far it's not working
[link](https://htaccessbook.com/htaccess-redirect-https-www/)
I updated what I posted because I seem to can't figure out how to format the codes in the comments

Comment: @LeKhiem So far it's still not working. The weird thing is that, if I send the request through the browser with the url,  it works well. I get a reply, but through app using guzzle. it doesn't and I get this issue for certain network.

Comment: $this->client = new GuzzleClient(['defaults' => [
    'verify' => false
]]);
Did you try it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the day, it was a issue in the server configuration that the company made. 
Sorry for bothering you with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Disable verifying SSL

```
$this->client = new GuzzleClient(['defaults' => [
    'verify' => false
]]);
```

Did you try it ?

Comment: I did but it didn't work. I am in talk with tech support to see if it isn't a server issue. I am testing on every network I can in the capital today. Hopefully it was the case.  Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it .